# Specifying the full compile command that netbeans uses to compile a C++ program?

Tags: c++, netbeans, command-line, properties, compilation

**Problem / Goal**
I am trying to figure out how to get full control over the netbeans compile command so that I can change it from:

'g++ main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp'

to:

'g++ main.cpp -Wall'

**Reason**
If I log into terminal and manually type: 'g++ main.cpp -Wall', my program will compile just fine. When I try to compile with netbeans, I see in console that it is executing 'g++ main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp', and that fails because main.cpp already includes foo.cpp and bar.cpp at the top of the file. I get "multiple definition of file/method" errors.

**Question**
So how would I go about changing the command so that it only includes main.cpp in the compile command? Better yet, how do you manually specify the entire command string?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your explanation, you are doing it wrong in the first place. When you have multiple cpp files, you compile each of them into a single object file and then link them together. Using #include to include a .cpp file is the wrong way to go - thats what header (.h) files are for.

Header files (.h) contain the declarations of code parts that are defined in C++ files (.cpp). By including a header, you can use functions that are defined elsewhere. That elsewhere maybe another object file (.o or .obj - created by gcc -c something.cpp) or a library file (.lib). When you have 3 cpp files, a.cpp, b.cpp, c.cpp and they are all using functions from each other, the compile cycle will be:

```
gcc -c a.cpp -> yields a.o
gcc -c b.cpp -> yields b.o
gcc -c c.cpp -> yields c.o

gcc -o program a.o b.o c.o -> yields program (executable)
```

Or shorthand:

```
gcc a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp -o program
```

When b.cpp needs a function defined in c.cpp, then b.cpp needs to

```
#include <c.h>
```

where c.h contains the declaration of functions that b needs to use.

When you do something like `#include "b.cpp"` in your source code, it is almost always just simply wrong.